# Boost asio UDP client not receiving data

Tags: c++, boost, udp, asio

I'm trying to send data from the server to a specific client using UDP, without making the client send data to the server first, without sending the server data at all. The problem is that the client waits for data using the
`receive_from()` function, and gets nothing. For some reason the server does manage to send data and after sending the whole payload, it closes itself, but I don't know to where it sends the data.
If I run the server without the client the data is also successfully sent, and I don't know why, isn't the server supposed to block the `send_to()` function until the data is sent?

this is where the client stops (part of my code):

```
void UDPclient::run()
{
    std::string relative_path = "assets/";
    std::thread thread_context = std::thread([&] {_io_context.run(); }); //start the context.
    file_info fileInfo;

    boost::asio::io_context::work idleWork(_io_context);
    boost::system::error_code error;

    udp::socket socket(_io_context); //the file descriptor 
    
    WirehairCodec decoder;

    udp::endpoint sender;
    memset(&fileInfo, sizeof(fileInfo), 0); //reset the struct to 0 (good practice)

    std::size_t bytes_transferred = socket.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(&fileInfo, sizeof(fileInfo)),
        sender);

    ...

    socket.close();
}
```

Server(part of my code):

```
int main()
{
    std::uint16_t port = 2000;
    file_info fileInfo;
    std::string filePath;
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    udp::socket socket(io_context, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));
    udp::endpoint destination(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), port);
    
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    const WirehairResult initResult = wirehair_init(); //initialize wirehair

    if(initResult != Wirehair_Success)
    {
        std::cout << "failed to initialize wirehair: " << initResult << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (ec)
        std::cerr << ec.message() << std::endl;
    else
    { 
        std::cout << "Enter the specified file (Full path) to send: ";
        std::cin >> filePath; 

        while (!boost::filesystem::exists(filePath))
        {
            std::cerr << "file doesn't exist." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter the specified file (Full path) to send: ";
            std::cin >> filePath;
        }

        read_fileToVector(filePath, vBuffer);
        file_info fileInfo;
        memset(&fileInfo, 0, sizeof(fileInfo)); // Always set the struct values to 0, good practice.

        //send file size, name
        fileInfo.size = vBuffer.size();
        strncpy(fileInfo.fileName, filePath.substr(filePath.find_last_of("/\\") + 1).c_str(), 
                  sizeof(fileInfo.fileName) - 1);
        std::cout << "name: " << fileInfo.fileName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "size: " << fileInfo.size << std::endl;

        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(&fileInfo, sizeof(fileInfo)), destination);
        socket.wait(socket.wait_write);

        ...
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that your packets are simply being dropped somewhere between your sender and receiver. UDP has no rate control and if you try and send too quickly packets will simply be dropped. The other possibility is some kind of firewall or NAT blocking the traffic

Comment: If UDP is sent faster than your local interface can serialize them onto the wire (bandwidth), they will simply be dropped. UDP has no guarantees, not even that the receiver will get them, and you _will_ lose UDP datagrams. If you need guarantees, use TCP or an application-layer protocol that does that.

Comment: The arguments to memset are int the wrong order as well

Comment: You haven't bound the client socket to port 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really enough code to tell, but there are a few smells that I can point out:

- the memset call is wrong. Since clearly `file_info` must be trivial and standard layout (for memset to be legal), why not aggregate-initialize it with empty initializer instead, with the same effect (default-initializing every member)?
- your context is apparently a class member, but you are starting a thread for each receive? That seems odd. I'd expect a single thread with the lifetime of the io_context/work.

  If you really want to reuse/restart the same io_context, keep in mind the need to call `.reset()` on it in between.
- You don't need to open/close a socket for each receive either
- You might want to bind your UDP socket to a specific port to receive on

What'd I'd expect to see is something similar to:

```
struct UDPclient {
    UDPclient(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port = DEFAULT_PORT)
        : socket_(ex, udp::v4())
        , port_(port)
    {
        socket_.bind({{}, port_});
    }

    bool run()
    {
        file_info fi{}; // value-initializes all members

        udp::endpoint sender;
        if (std::size_t n =
                socket_.receive_from(asio::buffer(&fi, sizeof(fi)), sender);
            n > file_info::HEADERLEN && fi.magic == file_info::MAGIC) //
        {
            // don't assume name will be zero terminated
            std::string_view name(fi.name.data(),
                                  strnlen(fi.name.data(), fi.name.max_size()));

            COUT << "Receiving " << fi.xfer_id << " length " << fi.file_length
                 << " name " << std::quoted(name) << " from " << sender
                 << std::endl;
            decoder_.reset(
                wirehair_decoder_create(nullptr, fi.file_length, PACKET_SIZE));

            if (!decoder_) {
                throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_decoder_create");
            }

            packet_info packet{};

            for (bool data_complete = false; !data_complete;) {
                if (auto len = socket_.receive_from(
                        asio::buffer(&packet, sizeof(packet)), sender);
                    n >= packet_info::HEADERLEN &&
                    packet.magic == packet_info::MAGIC &&
                    len == packet_info::HEADERLEN + packet.block_length) //
                {
                    if (fi.xfer_id != packet.xfer_id)
                        continue; // TODO concurrent receives

                    COUT << "(Incoming " << packet.block_length << " for "
                         << fi.xfer_id << " from " << sender << ")"
                         << std::endl;
                    // Attempt decode
                    switch (wirehair_decode(decoder_.get(), packet.id,
                                            packet.block.data(),
                                            packet.block_length)) //
                    {
                        case Wirehair_NeedMore: continue; break;
                        case Wirehair_Success: data_complete = true; break;
                        default: throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_decode");
                    }
                    COUT << "(data complete? " << std::boolalpha
                         << data_complete << ")" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            COUT << "Receive completed for " << fi.xfer_id << std::endl;

            // try to be safe about interpreting the output name
            auto spec = fs::relative(
                weakly_canonical(
                    relative_path /
                    fs::path(name).lexically_normal().relative_path()),
                relative_path);

            if (spec.empty())
                throw std::runtime_error("invalid file specification " + spec.native());

            auto target = relative_path / spec;
            fs::create_directories(target.parent_path());

            COUT << "Decoding to " << target << " for " << fi.xfer_id
                 << std::endl;
            std::vector<uint8_t> decoded(fi.file_length);

            // Recover original data on decoder side
            auto r = wirehair_recover(decoder_.get(), decoded.data(),
                    decoded.size());

            if (r != Wirehair_Success)
                throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_recover");

            std::ofstream(target, std::ios::binary)
                .write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(decoded.data()),
                       decoded.size());
        }
        return true;
    }

  private:
    udp::socket socket_;
    uint16_t    port_;
    CodecPtr    decoder_{};
    fs::path    relative_path = "assets/";
};
```

For this I made up a protocol consisting of two types of messages with magic headers defined as:

```
namespace /*protocol*/ {
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct file_info {
        boost::endian::big_uint32_t magic, file_length;
        boost::uuids::uuid             xfer_id;
        std::array<char, PATH_MAX + 1> name;

        enum : unsigned {
            MAGIC     = 0xDEFACED,
            HEADERLEN = sizeof(magic) + sizeof(file_length) + sizeof(xfer_id),
        };
    };
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<file_info>);
    static_assert(sizeof(file_info) + 8 <= 0xFFFF); // must fit udp

    struct packet_info {
        boost::endian::big_uint32_t      magic, block_length, id;
        boost::uuids::uuid               xfer_id;
        std::array<uint8_t, PACKET_SIZE> block;
        enum : unsigned {
            MAGIC     = static_cast<unsigned>(~0xDEFACED),
            HEADERLEN = sizeof(magic) + sizeof(block_length) + sizeof(id) + sizeof(xfer_id)
        };
    };
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<packet_info>);
    static_assert(sizeof(packet_info) + 8 <= 0xFFFF); // must fit udp
#pragma pack(pop)

    // Rule Of Zero, please:
    struct WHFree {
        void operator()(WirehairCodec c) const { wirehair_free(c); }
    };

    using CodecPtr = std::unique_ptr<WirehairCodec_t, WHFree>;
} // namespace
```

Note also the exception-safe handle type `CodecPtr` that avoids any risk of leaking these resources.

### Full Demo Using Wirehair

Out of interest, I looked at the Wirehair codec and implemented a simple synchronous file transfer using it.

- One limitation is that zero-length files cannot be transferred (`wirehair_encoder_create` fails in that case). You'd have to create an exception to cover such cases.
- Also there is no graceful shutdown (that's because it's not possible to cancel blocking socket operations)
- Making the receiving end async would immediately unlock the possibility to receive several transfers simultaneiously. I already put a `xfer_id` field in to the protocol messages as a correlation id.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

#include <wirehair/wirehair.h>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace fs   = std::filesystem;
using asio::ip::udp;

static constexpr int      PACKET_SIZE  = 1400;
static constexpr uint16_t DEFAULT_PORT = 9797;

namespace /*protocol*/ {
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct file_info {
        boost::endian::big_uint32_t magic, file_length;
        boost::uuids::uuid             xfer_id;
        std::array<char, PATH_MAX + 1> name;

        enum : unsigned {
            MAGIC     = 0xDEFACED,
            HEADERLEN = sizeof(magic) + sizeof(file_length) + sizeof(xfer_id),
        };
    };
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<file_info>);
    static_assert(sizeof(file_info) + 8 <= 0xFFFF); // must fit udp

    struct packet_info {
        boost::endian::big_uint32_t      magic, block_length, id;
        boost::uuids::uuid               xfer_id;
        std::array<uint8_t, PACKET_SIZE> block;
        enum : unsigned {
            MAGIC     = static_cast<unsigned>(~0xDEFACED),
            HEADERLEN = sizeof(magic) + sizeof(block_length) + sizeof(id) + sizeof(xfer_id)
        };
    };
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<packet_info>);
    static_assert(sizeof(packet_info) + 8 <= 0xFFFF); // must fit udp
#pragma pack(pop)

    // Rule Of Zero, please:
    struct WHFree {
        void operator()(WirehairCodec c) const { wirehair_free(c); }
    };

    using CodecPtr = std::unique_ptr<WirehairCodec_t, WHFree>;
} // namespace

struct UDPclient {
    UDPclient(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port = DEFAULT_PORT)
        : socket_(ex, udp::v4())
        , port_(port)
    {
        socket_.bind({{}, port_});
    }

    bool run()
    {
        file_info fi{}; // value-initializes all members

        udp::endpoint sender;
        if (std::size_t n =
                socket_.receive_from(asio::buffer(&fi, sizeof(fi)), sender);
            n > file_info::HEADERLEN && fi.magic == file_info::MAGIC) //
        {
            // don't assume name will be zero terminated
            std::string_view name(fi.name.data(),
                                  strnlen(fi.name.data(), fi.name.max_size()));

            std::cout << "Receiving " << fi.xfer_id << " length "
                      << fi.file_length << " name " << std::quoted(name)
                      << " from " << sender << std::endl;
            decoder_.reset(
                wirehair_decoder_create(nullptr, fi.file_length, PACKET_SIZE));

            if (!decoder_) {
                throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_decoder_create");
            }

            packet_info packet{};

            for (bool data_complete = false; !data_complete;) {
                if (auto len = socket_.receive_from(
                        asio::buffer(&packet, sizeof(packet)), sender);
                    n >= packet_info::HEADERLEN &&
                    packet.magic == packet_info::MAGIC &&
                    len == packet_info::HEADERLEN + packet.block_length) //
                {
                    if (fi.xfer_id != packet.xfer_id)
                        continue; // TODO concurrent receives

                    std::cout << "(Incoming " << packet.block_length << " for "
                              << fi.xfer_id << " from " << sender << ")"
                              << std::endl;
                    // Attempt decode
                    switch (wirehair_decode(decoder_.get(), packet.id,
                                            packet.block.data(),
                                            packet.block_length)) //
                    {
                        case Wirehair_NeedMore: continue; break;
                        case Wirehair_Success: data_complete = true; break;
                        default: throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_decode");
                    }
                    std::cout << "(data complete? " << std::boolalpha
                              << data_complete << ")" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            std::cout << "Receive completed for " << fi.xfer_id << std::endl;

            // try to be safe about interpreting the output name
            auto spec = fs::relative(
                weakly_canonical(
                    relative_path /
                    fs::path(name).lexically_normal().relative_path()),
                relative_path);

            if (spec.empty())
                throw std::runtime_error("invalid file specification " + spec.native());

            auto target = relative_path / spec;
            fs::create_directories(target.parent_path());

            std::cout << "Decoding to " << target << " for " << fi.xfer_id
                      << std::endl;
            std::vector<uint8_t> decoded(fi.file_length);

            // Recover original data on decoder side
            auto r = wirehair_recover(decoder_.get(), decoded.data(),
                    decoded.size());

            if (r != Wirehair_Success)
                throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_recover");

            std::ofstream(target, std::ios::binary)
                .write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(decoded.data()),
                       decoded.size());
        }
        return true;
    }

  private:
    udp::socket socket_;
    uint16_t    port_;
    CodecPtr    decoder_{};
    fs::path    relative_path = "assets/";
};

struct Sender {
    Sender(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port = DEFAULT_PORT)
        : socket_(ex, udp::v4())
        , port_(port)
    {
    }

    bool send(fs::path filespec)
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(filespec, std::ios::binary);
        std::vector<uint8_t> const contents(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),
                                            {});
        ifs.close();
        assert(contents.size() == fs::file_size(filespec));

        file_info fi{}; // value-initializes all members
        fi.magic       = file_info::MAGIC;
        fi.xfer_id     = boost::uuids::random_generator{}();
        fi.file_length = contents.size();
        strncpy(fi.name.data(), filespec.c_str(), fi.name.size() - 1);

        socket_.send_to(asio::buffer(&fi, sizeof(fi)), {{}, port_});

        // Create encoder
        encoder_.reset(wirehair_encoder_create(nullptr, contents.data(),
                                               contents.size(), PACKET_SIZE));
        if (!encoder_) {
            throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_encoder_create");
        }

        auto N = contents.size() / PACKET_SIZE + 1;
        N      = (N * 10) / 9; // ~10% redundancy

        std::cout << "Sending " << filespec << " of " << contents.size()
                  << " bytes in " << N << " packets of " << PACKET_SIZE
                  << std::endl;

        for (unsigned block_id = 1; block_id <= N; ++block_id) {
            sleep_for(500ms);
            packet_info packet{};
            packet.magic   = packet_info::MAGIC;
            packet.xfer_id = fi.xfer_id;

            // Encode a packet
            uint32_t writeLen = 0;
            if (auto r = wirehair_encode(encoder_.get(), block_id,
                                         packet.block.data(),
                                         packet.block.size(), &writeLen);
                r == Wirehair_Success) //
            {
                packet.id           = block_id;
                packet.block_length = writeLen;
                socket_.send_to(
                    asio::buffer(&packet, packet_info::HEADERLEN + writeLen),
                    {{}, port_});
                std::cout << "(Packet " << packet.block_length << " bytes)"
                          << std::endl;
            } else {
                throw std::runtime_error("wirehair_encode");
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Send " << filespec << " complete (xfer_id:" << fi.xfer_id
                  << ")" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

  private:
    udp::socket socket_;
    uint16_t    port_;
    CodecPtr    encoder_{};
    fs::path    relative_path = "assets/";
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (auto r = wirehair_init(); r != Wirehair_Success) {
        std::cout << "Wirehair initialization failed: " << r << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    asio::thread_pool io(1); 
    auto ex = io.get_executor();

    post(io, [ex] {
        UDPclient client{ex};
        while (true)
        try { client.run(); }
        catch (std::exception const& e) { std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n"; }
    });

    Sender sender{ex};
    for (auto spec : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        try {
            sender.send(spec);
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }

    io.join();
}
```

I cannot put the demo live online, but you can build it yourself with the repository at https://github.com/sehe/wirehair-demo:

[image]

Comment: Hehe. Somehow I had missed the "Server part of my code" from your question. It seems I  guessed mostly right :)

Comment: Note though that the protocol I showed guards against many more things, spurious packets (not containing the expected message types), misformed messages (too short, e.g.), non-terminated strings, network byte order (Big-endian on the wire), a unique transfer id to avoid mixing packets from unrelated transfers, to name a few.

Comment: Put the project on github so it's easy to build and demo locally https://github.com/sehe/wirehair-demo

Comment: Updated the repository to show concurrent senders and threaded  receiving. https://imgur.com/a/Fb4imQm

Comment: I can't express how much grateful I am to you, thank you for helping, it did help me but I changed my code according to your tips, didn't fully understood your code, but it looks much better than mine :) now it works.